# Torrent File Remover

Tags: python, beginner, file-system

This script to locate torrent files in a given directory, and if they have been seeding for 2 weeks, delete the files.

I realize the comments are overboard. The reason for that is it's being shared with people who don't program.

What should I have done differently?

```
import os  # for listdir(), path(), remove(), and getctime()
from time import time, ctime, sleep
import datetime as dt  # datetime to compare dates

# Path to torrents
torrents_folder = r'C:\users\user\torrents\folder'
# Torrent files as a list
torrents = os.listdir(torrents_folder)
# Months will be used to swap month prefix and corresponding month number
months = {"Jan": "01", "Feb": "02", "Mar": "03", "Apr": "04", "May": "05", "Jun": "06", "Jul": "07", "Aug": "08",
          "Sep": "09", "October": "10", "Nov": "11", "Dec": "12", }
# Set the number of days to elapse from creation date before file is deleted
days_to_wait = dt.timedelta(days=14)

# function to remove torrent    
def torrent_remover(month):
        # Format the date, casting month to string
        start_date = dt.datetime.strptime(str(month), "%m %d %Y")
        # Elapsed Time. See line 12
        end_date = start_date + days_to_wait
        # Today's date for comparison
        today = dt.datetime.today()

        if end_date <= today:
            print("Removing: ", torrent, "\tTorrent expired on", end_date)
            # Create full path from the torrent folder and torrent file
            torrent_files = os.path.join(torrents_folder, torrent)
            # Delete the torrents
            os.remove(torrent_files)
        else:
            print("Nothing to remove")
            exit()

# Start the loop
for torrent in torrents:
    if torrent.endswith(".torrent"):
        # Get date time from each file then join file and folder to create full path
        date = ctime(os.path.getctime(os.path.join(torrents_folder, torrent)))
        # Remove the timestamp
        remove_timestamp = date.replace(date[11:19], "")
        # Remove the day
        new_date = remove_timestamp.replace(remove_timestamp[0:4], "")
        # Return single value in list
        month = [month for month in months if month in new_date][0]
        if month in new_date:
            # Returns the month number when passed month key
            month_number = months[month]
            # Replace the month prefix with the corresponding number
            reformatted_date = new_date.replace(month, month_number)
            # Send to delete function to be deleted.
            torrent_remover(reformatted_date)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do with learning some of the more powerful tools in Python, such as `pathlib`.

Tracing control flow, instead of

```
torrents_folder = r'C:\users\user\torrents\folder'
torrents = os.listdir(torrents_folder)

for torrent in torrents:
    if torrent.endswith(".torrent"):
        ...
```

you can do

```
torrents_folder = Path(r'C:\users\user\torrents\folder')
for torrent_path in torrents_folder.glob("*.torrent"):
    ...
```

Then to get the date you can do just

```
datetime.date.fromtimestamp(torrent_path.stat().st_ctime)
```

Before I leave this, though, I should warn that your

```
text.replace(text[a:b], "")
```

to remove a slice is error-prone if that slice ever appears elsewhere. Instead try something like

```
text = text[:a] + text[b:]
```

Your `if` after

```
month = [month for month in months if month in new_date][0]
if month in new_date:
```

looks strange - of course it will be `True` since you've just checked for it.

Anyway, this can now be avoided entirely since we have a `date` object.

You run `torrent_remover(date)` (although you call it `month` in the call signature!), but you also need the `torrent_path`. It turns out you're passing this as a global! That's bad!

Instead, add another parameter so you have

```
def torrent_remover(path, date):
```

Your checks can then just be

```
end_date = date + days_to_wait
today = dt.datetime.today()

if end_date <= today:
    ...
else:
    ...
```

Your

```
print("Removing: ", torrent, "\tTorrent expired on", end_date)
torrent_files = os.path.join(torrents_folder, torrent)
os.remove(torrent_files)
```

Is misnamed (you only remove one file), but now can be just

```
print("Removing: ", torrent_path, "\tTorrent expired on", end_date)
torrent_path.unlink()
```

and your other path looks wrong:

```
print("Nothing to remove")
exit()
```

since `exit` quits the process entirely.

`days_to_wait` is a global constant, so should be uppercase. However, I would put the code in a `main` function and just pass it to the remover.

I would let `torrent_remover` get the date itself, simplifying the main loop.

Finally, your printing adds spaces between every part. One way to fix that is

```
print(a, b, c, sep="")
```

but it seems better to use formatting here:

```
print("{}{}{}".format(a, b, c))
```

This all gives

```
from datetime import date, timedelta
from pathlib import Path

def torrent_remover(path, shelf_life):
    created_on = date.fromtimestamp(torrent_path.stat().st_ctime)
    expired_on = created_on + shelf_life

    if expired_on <= date.today():
        print("Removing: {}\tTorrent expired on {}".format(torrent_path, expired_on))
        torrent_path.unlink()

def main():
    shelf_life = timedelta(days=14)
    torrents_folder = Path(r"C:\users\user\torrents\folder")

    for torrent_path in torrents_folder.glob("*.torrent"):
        torrent_remover(torrent_path, shelf_life)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

which I hope you'll agree is simpler. To add a check for if any file has been removed, try something like

```
from datetime import date, timedelta
from pathlib import Path

def torrent_remover(path, shelf_life):
    created_on = date.fromtimestamp(torrent_path.stat().st_ctime)
    expired_on = created_on + shelf_life

    if expired_on <= date.today():
        print("Removing: {}\tTorrent expired on {}".format(torrent_path, expired_on))
        torrent_path.unlink()
        return True

    return False

def main():
    shelf_life = timedelta(days=14)
    torrent_paths = Path(r"C:\users\user\torrents\folder").glob("*.torrent")
    removed = sum(torrent_remover(path, shelf_life) for path in torrent_paths)

    if not removed:
        print("Nothing to remove")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This is untested.

Answer (score 2):

This is by no means complete feedback, but I hope some of these comments are useful.

I’ll be honest, I got a bit lost in your for loop and I’m too tired to unpick exactly what it does. Your variable names are particularly confusing. I may write some more later if I go back to look at that block of code again.

---

#### General comments

- The comments are indeed overboard. Comments should explain *why* you’re doing something, not *how* you’re doing it. The latter can easily become stale and out-of-date.

  If this script is meant for non-programmers, then it’s probably enough to provide a high-level comment explaining what it does in broad terms. For example, you might add a comment to `torrent_remover()` saying:

  > This function takes [some arguments – see below] and deletes the associated torrent file if it is more than (days_to_wait) days old.

  That’s probably all they need to know.

  Non-programmers won’t read your detailed comments about program flow, and programmers will find them distracting.
- Consider your description:

  > This script to locate torrent files in a given directory, and if they have been seeding for 2 weeks, delete the files.

  First, I can’t see anything in this script which checks if the files are seeding – simply how long they’ve been sitting there. A torrent which didn’t start downloading until day 13 would be deleted on day 14 of its existence by this program.

  Second, consider adding a doctoring right at the top of the module explaining what this script is supposed to do, any parameters you should change, and how to run it.

#### Comments on general Python style

- Module imports should be alphabetically ordered, and you don’t need a comment to say why you’re importing the module. (It will get out of date quickly.) The Python style guide has some rules about [formatting module imports](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports).

  - Why are you importing datetime as dt? It doesn’t save many characters, but it makes it harder to read your program.
- It’s better not to have all your variables in global scope. Wrap as much in functions as possible – this  makes it easier to reuse bits of code in other scripts.

  For the mainline program flow, wrap it in a `main()` function. Then you wrap that in an if main block, that looks like this:

  ```
  if __name__ == '__main__':
      main()
  ```

  at the end of the script. The `main()` function is only executed if you run the script directly.
- You’ve got a comment about your `torrent_remover()` function explaining what it does, but the preferred way to explain what a function does in Python is to use a docstring. That’s a triple-quoted string, as the first thing in the function.

#### Global variables

The program starts with some global variables. Here are my thoughts:

- Have a comment right at the start saying that these are your global constants. It makes it easy for somebody else to see that these are the variables they have to change. I also prefer to give these variable names CAPITAL LETTERS to make them stand out.
- There are four variables here, but the user should only ever need to change two of them (torrents_folder and days_to_wait). Separate them from the others to make them stand out.
- If I want to change days_to_wait, the name suggests I’m going to be putting in a number. What’s this dt.timedelta() stuff? Have this variable be an integer, and transform it to a datetime object later. It makes it easier to see the purpose of this variable, and hides some of the complexity from your non-programmer friends.
- Rather than writing your months object by hand, use the `calendar` module. The less code you have to write, the better:

  ```
  import calendar

  months = ({month: str(num).zfill(2) for (num, month) in enumerate(calendar.month_abbr)}
  ```
- Rather than constructing paths by hand (even if you did use `r'...'`), it's better to use `os.path.join()`. This is more portable:

  ```
  TORRENTS_FOLDER = os.path.join('C:', 'Users', 'JohnSmith', 'Torrents')
  ```

#### torrent_remover()

- Your comment explaining it is very non-specific. What am I passing in? It looks like a number, but then you try to parse it in the format `%m %d %Y`, which doesn't look like a month format. This comment should be improved to explain what exactly the function is supposed to take.
- Rather than accessing the global `DAYS_TO_WAIT` variable directly, have the days_to_wait be an argument to the function. That makes it easier to use the function in other scripts.
- This function is using a `torrent` variable, but just reading the function, I don’t know where it comes from. This should be another argument to the function.
- The variable name `torrent_files` is plural but refers to a single file. It’s confusing.
- The function assumes that `os.remove()` will be successful. I’d add a check that the file has been successfully removed, and if not, print a warning to the user.
- I’d rename the function to `remove_torrent()`. I think function names should be verbs, not nouns.

#### for loop

- This is the block of code you should wrap in a `main()` function.
- Your variable names make it very difficult to follow this block of code.
- Rather than using `endswith()` to determine file extensions, look at using [`os.path.splitext()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.splitext) instead. More portable and reliable.

Answer (score 1):

You have

```
# Torrent files as a list
torrents = os.listdir(torrents_folder)
```

it seems that torrents is the list of torrents, but later you filter the list with

```
if torrent.endswith(".torrent"):
```

I would change it to:

```
torrents = [torrent for torrent in os.listdir(torrents_folder)
               if torrent.endswith(".torrent")]
```

Then you have

```
# function to remove torrent    
def torrent_remover(month):
```

From the name I would suspect that it removes all torrents of a month when it instead removes the torrent if the creation date is old.

I would change the name to remove_old_torrent (remove as a verb, because it is a function) and also include the getting the creation date in the function:

```
# function to remove old torrent    
def remove_old_torrent(torrent_path):
```

There is also an easier way to convert ctime to datetime (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10256093/how-to-convert-ctime-to-datetime-in-python):

```
dt.datetime.strptime(ctime(os.path.getctime(torrent_path)), "%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y")
```

The following aborts the program if the a torrent is old and the rest of the files are not checked. (also exit should not be used in programs (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6501121/the-difference-between-exit-and-sys-exit-in-python))

```
else:
    print("Nothing to remove")
    exit()
```

The total code would look like this(untested):

```
import os  # for listdir(), path(), remove(), and getctime()
from time import time, ctime
import datetime as dt  # datetime to compare dates

# Path to torrents
torrents_folder = r'C:\users\user\torrents\folder'
# Torrent files as a list
torrents = [torrent for torrent in os.listdir(torrents_folder)
                   if torrent.endswith(".torrent")]

# Set the number of days to elapse from creation date before file is deleted
days_to_wait = dt.timedelta(days=14)

# function to remove torrent    
def remove_old_torrent(torrent_path):
        # Get file creation date
        start_date = dt.datetime.strptime(ctime(os.path.getctime(torrent_path)), "%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y")
        # Elapsed Time. See line 12
        end_date = start_date + days_to_wait
        # Today's date for comparison
        today = dt.datetime.today()

        if end_date <= today:
            print("Removing: ", os.path.basename(torrent_path), "\tTorrent expired on", end_date)
            # Delete the torrent
            os.remove(torrent_path)
            return True
        else:
            return False


file_removed = False
# Start the loop
for torrent in torrents:
        # join file and folder to create full path
        torrent_path = os.path.join(torrents_folder, torrent)
        if remove_old_torrent(torrent_path):
             file_removed = True

if not file_removed:
        print("Nothing to remove")
```

Comment: FWIW, `datetime.date.fromtimestamp(os.path.getctime(torrent_path))` (see my answer).